# Can't launch Teams as root on Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code, syslinux, microsoft-teams

I'm using Ubuntu I just installed Teams Desktop and VisualStudioCode.
I can launch and use these software with normal user account but impossible to launch them on my root account. Can't find anything on internet, does anyone could help me please ?

Comment: Is there an error message when you run it on terminal? Also, this may be an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why do you need to run teams as root?

Comment: This is by design and not a problem. We take security serious :-)

Comment: Thanks for you messages.
Actually why is not the question, but how can I resolve this issue. Don't be worry for me if use it as root :)

Answer (score 5):

You should **never** **ever** launch Teams or Visualstudiocode as root.

There is no sensible reason to start Teams as root.

For an editor, you probably consider editing system files. This can be done in a safe way, without having to elevate the privileges of a graphical application, with the following command

```
env SUDO_EDITOR=<path_to_Visualstudio> sudoedit <file>
```

Your sudo password will be asked, and a copy of the file will be opened for editing as user. When you close the editor, the system file is updated.

Comment: Hi vanadium, thx for your message.
My OS is completly isolated so there's not security risk. I just would like to know how to launch Teams as root by curiosity

Comment: @Kenway57 As commented above, *this is by design*, end of story.